# Removing datatype information line from python head function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to access the top 6 items in a pandas dataframe.
I am doing this by using `.head(n=6)`. This works fine and will show me the first 6 values. my problem is that it also shows the type of data that the data is. In this case I have my 6 values and at the bottom of my values I see : `Name: Column 7, dtype: int64`.

When I do:

```
Print(df_column_7.head(n=6)
```

I get 6 values and an additional datatype line.

I am struggling to find a way to remove the this additional data type information provided by `.head()`.
I want to get rid of this data type information as I will be adding the `.head(n=6)` into a Django model. And the datatype info will mess up the model entry.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the datatype info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your use `head` on `pandas series`, you'll get this line by default.

```
>>> d = pd.Series(list('abcdefg'), name='col_1').to_frame() 

>>> d.col_1.head(n=3)
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: col_1, dtype: object
```

If you need to omit last line, you can do:

```
>>> print(d.col_1.head(n=3).to_string())
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not see the problem with a dataframe I have tested.
So I could not try, but try and let me know if this helps:

```
display(df_column_7.head(6))
```